# How do I solve this tricky definite integral ?!

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$I=\int\limits_0^1\dfrac{x^2-1}{\ln x}\mathrm dx$$

I tried numerous substitutions but nothing seems to work.. any ideas ???!

Comment: [$$\int_0^1\frac{x^\alpha-1}{\ln x}\ dx=\ln(\alpha+1)$$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/827584/123277)

Comment: @Tunk-Fey. Could you elaborate, please. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Just click the cited link.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey. Thanks (I did not "see" the link - I am almost blind). Cheers :-)

Comment: Haha, Feynman's infamous trick !!! Didn't expect to see this here +1 @Tunk-Fey

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It's OK. I think it's my fault since the cited link is too vague. :)